# passthru() + Pipe in subprocess = Traceback (most recent call last): (…) in stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Tags: subprocess, pipe, traceback, passthru

I've got an error when I'm using passthru() to call a python script (using subprocess and pipe) with PHP.

Here is the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "…/Desktop/h.py", line 11, in stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>     #set up the convert command and direct the output to a pipe
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/subprocess.py", line 593, in __init__
>     errread, errwrite)
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/subprocess.py", line 1079, in _execute_child
>     raise child_exception
> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> ```

The PHP passthru:

```
<?php
passthru("/usr/bin/python2.5 /Users/Nagar/Desktop/h.py $argument1 $argument2 1 2>&1");
?>
```

My Python line which cause the error:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['convert', fileIn, 'pnm:-'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #set up the convert command and direct the output to a pipe
```

How to use stdout=subprocess.PIPE properly in the subprocess?

Looking forward your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your PATH doesn't have the directory including the "convert" command. Try replacing:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['convert', fileIn, 'pnm:-'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

with:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['/full/path/to/convert', fileIn, 'pnm:-'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

where "/full/path/to/convert" might be something like "/usr/bin/convert".

Answer (score 0):

It's because it needs to be executed through a shell, so you need to set shell argument to True:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['convert', fileIn, 'pnm:-'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)convert command and direct the output to a pipe
```